# Flask Python mkdirs returns "Permission denied" over mounted drive

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, mkdirs

I have an app that creates directories on a mounted SMB network drive, but the app is returning "Permission denied" errors.  If I run the same code locally as sudo it works just fine.

I'm utilizing Gunicorn, Supervisor, & Nginx on the server and I'm assuming that I need to set permissions somewhere for my app to work properly.  But I'm unsure where that is.

For context I've been using the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux) as a guide, but because my app has different functionality it didn't really address some specific needs such as this.  I'm hoping someone could provide me with some more guidance.

Update: Seems this issue had to do with the SMB being mounted without the proper permissions.

Comment: You have admin access to the SMB drive to change settings?

Comment: @Reedinationer Yes I was actually coming to update the thread.  Seems like my IT department set up the mounting without setting permissions properly   I generally trust them which is why I was thinking it was a problem on my end.

Comment: No, it is a problem in the permissions of the folder for sure. I get the same error at work if IT sets a folder as unreachable. Guess you should answer your own question to explain that, and accept the answer so the thread closes, right?

Comment: I'm unsure how to mark it answered.  But the issue was with the fstab file that holds the configuration for the SMB mount.  The domain name wasn't added properly.

Comment: You would have to answer your own question using the box below, where you would explain what the solution to your problem was and why. You could then click the check mark by it to accept it as the answer. Alternatively, if you think nobody will find future value reading your explanation of the solution you can delete the question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get this marked as solved.

The issue was with the fstab file that holds the configuration for the SMB mount. The domain name wasn't added properly